# php code is not running and getting no error message about the sql statement

Tags: php

I am using the following form

```
<section id="formSection">
  <form id="dataForm" action="addUser.php" method="post">
  <div>
    <h2>Add Product:</h2>
    <lable>First Name:</lable>
    <input class="inputForm" id="inputFirstName" type="text" name="firstname">
  </div>
  <div>
    <lable>Last Name:</lable>
    <input class="inputForm" id="inputLastName"  type="text" name="lastname">
  </div>
  <div>
    <lable>Address:  </lable>
    <input class="inputForm" id="inputAdress" type="text" name="address">
  </div>
  <div>
    <lable>Post Code:</lable>
    <input class="inputForm" id="inputPostcode" type="text" name="postcode">
  </div>
  <div>
    <lable>Delievery Type:</lable>
    <input class="inputForm" id="inputDelievery" type="text" name="delievery">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
  </form>
</section>
```

and the following php code to add entries from the form to the database.

```
 $FirstName = $_POST[firstname];
     $LastName = $_POST[lastname];
     $address = $_POST[address];
     $postcode = $_POST[postcode];
     $delivery = $_POST[delievery];

     $sql = "INSERT INTO USERS (FIRSTNAME, SECONDNAME, ADDRESS, POSTCODE, DELIVERY_TYPE) 
             VALUES ('$FirstName', '$LastName', '$address', '$postcode', '$delivery')";
     $conn->exec($sql);
```

However it is not working, and having stared at the screen for the last 2 hours trying to fix it.

Comment: You're not getting errors, because you're NOT checking for them and you have a few. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Reload my comment. Plus, which API are you using to connect with, PDO?

Comment: Stack's being a pain in the *** today. Pass it on...

Comment: It seems you're using PDO, right? Use prepared statements if you're going to use it.

Comment: yes i am using PDO, but am very new to it, i will have to go look up prepared statements but thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your POST arrays are missing quotes:

```
$FirstName = $_POST[firstname];
```

should read as

```
$FirstName = $_POST['firstname'];
```

and do the same for the rest.

Plus, since you seem to be using PDO, use prepared statements instead.

You're open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).

- http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Error reporting would have spotted the parse errors.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

I also suggest you check if any fields are left empty, by using a conditional `empty()` for your form elements.

Otherwise, you may get a notice from MySQL, depending on how your table is setup.

I.e.:

```
if(!empty($_POST['firstname'])){
   $FirstName = $_POST['firstname'];
}
```

For all:

```
if(
    !empty($_POST['firstname']) && 
    !empty($_POST['lastname'])  && 
    !empty($_POST['address'])   && 
    !empty($_POST['postcode'])  && 
    !empty($_POST['delievery']) 
)

{

    $FirstName =  $_POST['firstname'];
    $LastName  =  $_POST['lastname'];
    $address   =  $_POST['address'];
    $postcode  =  $_POST['postcode'];
    $delivery  =  $_POST['delievery'];

}
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: thank you, this has been alot of help, i will accept the answer for you when the time limit runs out!

Comment: @Dave5678 You're welcome. I also made a slight edit since about `$_POST['delievery']` which grammatically speaking, should read as `$_POST['delivery']`, check that in your form, just to be sure.

Comment: About `error_reporting`. Perhaps it would be more correct to say _`display_errors` should only be done in staging, and never production_.

Comment: @Cthulhu You have a point there, but I've been asked to change this so many times lol we'll just leave your comment there, if you don't mind. I will upvote it.

Comment: @Dave5678 I've made an additional edit in regards to checking for empty fields.